# Access HttpServlet response from GWT client

Tags: servlets, gwt

we have the following scenario:

We want to show an html output from our reporting framework within the gwt client.
We have access to this generated html content via an HttpServlet that writes its output to

```
HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()
```

We already had a look at RequestBuilder. But the response does not look like the one from the HttpServlet.

Is there any chance to access data from a HttpServlet response in GWT?

Regards
Ben

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind introduce `GQuery` in your project, you can do it easily with Ajax features.

Take a look into the official Documentation:

https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax

But basically something like:

```
Settings settings = Ajax.createSettings()
    .setUrl("my/url")
    .setDataType("txt") // txt, json, jsonp, xml
    .setType("get")     // post, get
    .setData(GQuery.$$("param1: 1, param2: 2")) // parameters for the query-string
    .setTimeout(3000);

Ajax.ajax(settings)
  .done(new Function(){ public void f() {
    for (int i=0; i<getArguments().length; i++) {
      Object arg = getArgument(i);
      Window.alert("Argument["+i+"] - "+arg.toString());
    }
  }}).fail(new Function(){ public void f() {
    Window.alert("There was an error doing Ajax call");
  }});
```

If that does not work, check if the request has been done correctly (F12 on Chrome > Network), my response was assuming the request in the `Servlet` has been handled correctly.